# Mouse click object unity 5.3 UI?

Tags: javascript, user-interface, unity-game-engine

I'm currently working on a project that is due Monday for school. I've been working on it for a while, but when it comes to coding I always unable to solve any errors since I'm practically a beginner. How should I format my code so every time I click an object GUI appears? I'm currently using Unity version 5.3.

Code:

```
#pragma strict

 var scanners : UIText //variable for GUI text

 function Start () //scanner not clicked

 {
     scanners.enabled=false;
}

 function OnMouseDown() //scanner clicked

 {
     scanners.enabled=true;
}

 function OnMouseUp() //scanner unclicked

 {

     scanners.enabled=false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

GUI elements are drawn inside the OnGUI() function. but this is an old way of doing things. Since Unity 5 you can just add a UI text element `(rightclick hierarchy >  UI > Text)` or use the `3D Text`, and then `gameObject.SetActive(true/false);` on that text when you run the `OnMouseDown/Up()` functions.

Comment: Please mark this answer if it answered what you needed. Thank you :)